# C Balanced brackets using Stack as Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to code Balanced brackets using Stack as Linked List in C. The problem I am facing is that when the test case value is 3 , the first two test cases are working fine but the last one is showing NO always as output.
for eg:
if the input is:

```
3

{[()]}

{[(])}

{{[[(())]]}}
```

The expected output is:

```
YES
NO 
YES
```

The actual output is:

```
YES
NO 
NO
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
}*top = NULL;

void push(char x)
{
    struct Node *t;
    t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(t == NULL)
        printf("Stack is Overflow\n");
    else
    {
        t->data = x;
        t->next = top;
        top=t;
    }
}

char pop()
{
    char x = -1;
    struct Node *p;
    if(top == NULL)
        printf("Stack is Underflow\n");
    else
    {
        p=top;
        top=top->next;
        x=p->data;
        free(p);
    }
    return x;
}

int isEmpty()
{
    return top?0:1;
}

char stackTop()
{
    if(!isEmpty())
        return top->data;
    return '0';
}

int isBalanced(char *exp)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;exp[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            push(exp[i]);
        else if(exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            if(isEmpty())
                return 0;
            if(stackTop() == '(' && exp[i] == ')')
                pop();
            else if(stackTop() == '{' && exp[i] == '}')
                pop();
            else if(stackTop() == '[' && exp[i] == ']')
                pop();
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
        if(isEmpty())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}


int main()
{
    char *exp;
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        exp = (char*)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",exp);
        if(isBalanced(exp))
            printf("YES\n");
        else 
            printf("NO\n");
        free(exp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reset the stack after dealing with each cases.

```
    while(t--)
    {
        exp = (char*)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",exp);
        if(isBalanced(exp))
            printf("YES\n");
        else 
            printf("NO\n");
        free(exp);
        while (!isEmpty()) pop(); /* add this */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    char data;
    struct  Node *next;
}*top = NULL;

void push(char x){
    struct Node *t;
    t = new Node;
    if(t == NULL){
        cout<<"Stack is full"<<endl;

    }
    else{
        t->data = x;
        t->next = top;
        top = t;
    }


}
char pop(){
    char x = -1;
    struct Node *p;
    if(top == NULL){
        cout<<"stack is empty"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        p = top;
        top = top->next;
        x = p->data;
        delete p;
    }
    return x;
}
char stackTop(){
    if(top){
        return top->data;
    }
    return '0';
}

int isBalanced(char exp[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; exp[i] != '\0';i++){
        if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '[' || exp[i] == '{'){
            push(exp[i]);
        }
        else if(exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == ']' || exp[i] == '}'){
            if(top == NULL){
                return 0;
            }if( stackTop() == '(' && exp[i] == ')'){
                pop();
            }else if(stackTop() == '{' && exp[i] == '}'){
                pop();
            }else if(stackTop() == '[' && exp[i] == ']'){
                pop();
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return top == NULL? 1 : 0;
}

int main(){
    // exp
    char  exp[] = "{([a+b]*(b-c])}";

   if(isBalanced(exp)){
    cout<<"Balanced Parenthesis"<<endl;
   }else{
    cout<<"Not Balanced"<<endl;
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).